# Is there a way to move Pokemon from a ROM to a Physical cartridge?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation, emulation, nintendo-ds

I was traveling for a while and forgot my Nintendo DS, so I started playing on an emulator. During this time I played Pokemon Black 2.

I've grown particularly fond of my team. I now am back home but with a Pokemon save file on OpenEmu for Mac. I have a copy of Black 2 (as in physical cartridge) and am wondering if there's any way I can transfer my Pokemon over from Black 2 ROM to Black 2 legit cartridge.

My eventual goal would be to bring these Pokémon into X and Y.

Comment: @Close Voters - How is this off-topic? Emulation is [on-topic](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/102/28182), the OP has a physical copy of the game, and wants to continue to use said physical copy. Taking a copy for backup/archival or for use on another device is covered under fair use

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can. However you need some special hardware.

First you need a Flashcart. A flash cart is an special cartridge which allows the use of homebrew in the DS. Homebrew software is software developed by the community to be used on certain device or environment. This homebrew usually comes in the form of roms or similar.

With that said, you can use such a Flashcart to load a .rom into it, and then use your DS with that cartridge to launch the .rom. Now given that you already have a save file you want to transfer, you need to copy the save file to the Flashcart too, these files are usually placed besides the rom, by the respective emulator.

Now, following this process you cannot transfer the pokemon between your Flashcart and the X and Y games, because of some security measures implemented by Nintendo. So you need to transfer them to a previous generation game first. Which is great given that you do have the Black cartridge.

So, to transfer the pokemon between the two Black versions you need two DS with the respective cartridges, and use the Union Room to transfer the pokemon.

Once you got your pokemon into the real cartridge, you can transfer them to X and Y using Pokemon Bank.

Note: I have not done the process myself, but some time ago, I was thinking about getting X and Y, and looked up about the transfer possibilities. And i read some tutorials explaining what I stated above.

Comment: This is how I have brought teams from emulators onto real hardware. As long as you haven't hacked your team with unobtainable EV/IV/moves/abilities, they should trade through just fine and should be able to transfer up generations as well if you choose.

Answer (score 4):

Couple ways I can think of.

1. Utilizing an [ActionReplay](http://us.codejunkies.com) system to turn the Pokémon to code, and then transfer them to ActionReplay in your physical game
2. Using a [Flash cart](http://www.modsupplier.com/catalog/ds-flash-card-c-47_49.html) to import your whole save file in the emulator to a new physical cartridge
3. Use [Pokegen](http://projectpokemon.org/pokegen/) to recreate your team manually. You'll need to know all the pertinent data, though, like secret ID and actual regions.

Sky3DS (my rec): http://www.sky3ds.com

Answer (score 0):

For those of you in 2021 who need this answer:
If you have a hacked 3DS, you can use homebrew provided tools to dump saves.

Using Checkpoint, you can save the save file from a cartridge to the SD card for transferring into an emulator. Having a hacked 3DS would easily allow you to do this.

---

To transfer Pokemon from X to Y, (or even Yellow VC to Sun) downloading PKSM 3DS will allow you to freely move Pokemon between Generations 1-7, provided you have those games. This will require your console to be running The Homebrew Launcher or Luma3DS CFW.

NOTE: Homebrewing consoles is still a self-expense risk, but I've had no problems with homebrew for the last 6 years. Provided you do it correctly, it's really wonderful.

Answer (score -5):

Unless you have something like this and all the set of software that it requires, you won't be able to move the save game across to the cartridge:

[image: Nintendo DS Dev Kit]

This 'toaster' is used to develop NDS games and can write on cartridge memory.

I would suggest to support game companies by purchasing their games and not using emulators; game developers spend a lot of time and energy to bring you good games, they should be rewarded :)

Comment: Downvoters should comment :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/193762

Comment: @Frank Yes, I know :/ I'm not worried. It's just that if there is a better answer, one should post it! Heh!

Comment: Downvotes are probably because OP explained in detail that he does have the original game and had his reasons to play on emulator for a while. There are people who prefer playing on emulator, so they will commonly buy a game to suport the devs, then download or rip the ROM to play on their emulator.