# Is it possible to move a GBA save file from an emulator to a physical cartridge?

Tags: emulation, game-boy-advance

So a couple months ago I found an emulator for one of my favorite Game Boy games Mario and Luigi Superstar Saga. The app I used stopped working so I cannot play it from there, but my save file exists through my Dropbox. Just a few days ago, I bought the actual cartridge (and it came in yesterday) from GameStop, and I want to continue from where I left off. Is it possible to move the save file from the emulator to the cartridge or do I have to start over?

Comment: There is [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/203691/is-there-a-way-to-move-pokemon-from-a-rom-to-a-physical-cartridge) Q/A regarding DS Roms. While it isn't for GBA, it still might point you in the right direction

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You can do so by running the DS homebrew software [GBA Backup Tool](http://gamebrew.org/wiki/GBA_Backup_Tool) on a DS or DS Lite by using a flashcart. Despite its name, it can restore saves too. You will have to make sure your save is in the "raw" format, rather than a special emulator-specific one.