# Can you move a modded DS game ROM into physical copy then play it on unhacked 3DS?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-ds, physical-media

I have a unhacked 3DS handheld which contains many games, and I won't hack it because it is so smooth and well maintained like new. And I have so many physical games.

There's a certain game called Gyakuten Kenji 2 or fans calls it Ace Attorney Investigation 2 for NDS and never released outside Japan. But somehow they managed to translate and mod the ROM with English patch. I have a bad habit when into a series collection, when into collecting physical copies I tend into obsession.

My question is, can we move the modded ROM into a physical copy then play it on the unhacked 3DS handheld?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

As the full form of the acronym ROM implies ("**Read-Only** Memory"), once data (in the case of cartridge-based consoles, the game itself) has been written to the chip, it's locked into a read-only state (i.e. you won't be able to write **anything** onto the cartridge.)

Comment: The ROM is read-only, but [save data can still be written to the cartridge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/203691/181240).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flashcart to play the ROM on a 3DS. It's also possible to mod your 3DS. I understand that you want to keep it clean, But modding your 3DS won't change performance.

If you really do not want to mod your 3DS, Just use a flashcart or a bootleg DS game. You can use GM9 on your DS (if you have a modded DS) to copy the ROM to the cheap bootleg. Bootlegs are easy to find on eBay. From my experience, I use a modded 3DS. I used to use a flashcart. If you are too lazy to do any of this, you can use an emulator like DeSmuME or MelonDS.